# using Axe-core inside Intern 4

Tags: systemjs, intern

I am trying to set up my accessibility testing using axe-core or axe-webdriverjs inside of Intern 4. I finally got something to compile but I get this socket hung up error. Let me walk you through my process.

1. Loading axe-core as a plugin. In my intern.json 
   I have my included a plugin axe-core.  `node_modules/axe-core/axe.min.js` specified here https://axe-core.org/. This did not work. When running the test it did not find the module.
2. I then tried using the loader to import this module. In my intern.json I had the following:

   `"plugins": [
           "node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js"
       ],`

installed the necessary plugins and then I imported axe in my test.js using:

```
`import axe from '/node_modules/axe-core/axe.min'`
```

still I get axe is undefined errors.

3. I tried to use axe-webdriverjs used the example code

   ```
   const { suite, test, before } = intern.getInterface('tdd');
   const { assert } = intern.getPlugin('chai');
   var AxeBuilder = require('axe-webdriverjs');


   var time = 1000;
   var session; 

   suite('Accessibility', () => {
       test('Accessibility Test 1', ({remote}) =>  {
           remote.get('https://dequeuniversity.com/demo/mars/')
           .then(function () {
             AxeBuilder(driver)
               .analyze(function (results) {
                 console.log(results);
               });
           });
       });
   });
   ```

still could not get it to work.

4. then I tried changing the
        `var AxeBuilder = require('axe-webdriverjs');`
   to
   `import  AxeBuilder from  'node_modules/axe-webdriverjs/lib/index';`

It is now running but I get a socket hang up error.

All I am trying to do is run axe-core or even axe-webdriver a thrid party library into tests suite within intern 4. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an Intern [accessibility plugin](https://github.com/theintern/intern-a11y) that includes support for aXe. You can use that directly, or simply use it as an example of how to use aXe-core with Intern.

You wouldn't typically use axe-webdriverjs with Intern since Intern is using its own WebDriver library which isn't directly compatible with the Selenium JS library.